# How to switch a word with a digit in a line in shell using sed

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I have a question regarding on how to switch a number (1-infinity) with a character or a word:

Here is my code:

```
sed  's/ ([a-z]*) ([0-9]*)/\2 \1/g'> $file_output
```

so I have the output (before using the command above) as

```
1 a
45 adam
```

and the intended output from using the sed command:

```
a 1
adam 45
```

but the line wouldn't work, specifically due to a syntax error. Here is the error that comes up:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 28: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS
```

How can I achieve my desired output?

Comment: Use extended regex support: `sed -r  's/ ([a-z]*) ([0-9]*)/\2 \1/g' "$file_output"`

Comment: either use `-r/-E` or escape the brackets.

Comment: Are there always two fields and is the requirement always to switch them? If so, you could use `awk '{ print $2, $1 }' file`.

Comment: @TomFenech That doesn't check whether they are numeric or not.

Comment: @123 I know but based on the sample input it might be enough!

Comment: Your sed expression says _search for a string of alphas followed by a string of digits_ (`([a-z]*) ([0-9]*)`) _and switch them over_ (`\2 \1`) but your input (i.e. _"before using the command above"_) is a number followed by a name?

Answer (score 3):

You need to backslash the parentheses to make them into grouping ones:

```
s/\([a-z]*\) \([0-9]*\)/\2 \1/g'
```

Or, if your sed supports it, use `-r` or `-E` to indicate you're using extended regular expressions.

Answer (score -3):

Using `sed  's/\(.*\) \(.*\)/\2 \1/'` is a general way of switching any alphanumeric with another.

Comment: Using `awk '{ print $2, $1 }'` is a general way of switching any two fields around but this wasn't your original requirement.